# Can you get rich off of the Death note?

Tags: death-note

If you write instructions to take out a big loan, convert it into cash (or a nontraceable valuable), take out all your other cash and then drop it off a predetermined location and then die somewhere else by 'insert random cause here' could you become extremely rich off of dying criminals?  (Or anyone if you are without scruples.)

Comment: As always, one with a Death Note can do anything that doesn't infringe the [Rules of the Death Note](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note).

Comment: I feel like people would get suspicious though, if you suddenly came into very large amounts of money from strange sources.

Comment: Agreed, you'd have to cover your tracks carefully, similar to mobsters who launder money.  Especially if Kira related criminals were giving to the same person, pretty much points the finger.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes.

Based on the experiments Light did with criminals, as long as what is written in the death note is humanly possible it will happen. Like the criminals who wrote suicide notes and drew figures on the wall before they died. But if it is not possible they simply die of heart attacks, like the guy who was supposed to die in Paris but it was impossible for him to escape from prison and flee to Paris and then die there in the limited time that was written for him.

If you carefully plan the robbery and the timing and placing is not impossible for the victim to arrive at, it will happen.